# Alert Dialog Unable to add window Error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create `AlertDialog` from `RecyclerView.Adapter` with this code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppTheme));
alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.reserve_dialog);
alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

but I'm getting this error in logcat:

```
Theme: themes:{}
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

What is wrong?

Comment: use your context like this context = itemView.getContext();

Comment: there is no itemView in onbindviewholder @JhamanDas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you are passing context.getApplicationContext()

Instead of this pass activity context

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme));
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.reserve_dialog);
    alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

Comment: What Exception you are getting?

Comment: the same exception

Comment: When your are creating adapter constructor then ,have you passed correct context to it?

Comment: Im using recyclerview inside another one so im passing Activity.this to first recyclerview adapter then from fisrt one to second one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110530/discussion-between-sukhbir-and-amir-p).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getApplicationContext(), just use ActivityName.this.

```
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new  ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.AppTheme));
   alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.reserve_dialog);
   alertDialogBuilder.create();
   if(!isFinishing()){
    alertDialogBuilder.show();
   }
```

Comment: where did you created Alert dialog..In Activity or Fragment..?

Comment: in `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Comment: What are you passing in Adapter means Activity or context..? change Context to Activity.

Comment: I'm passing `Activity.this`. i think i need to addflag like intent but i cant find how

Comment: Its working even with context. Working perfectly for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110528/discussion-between-saritha-g-and-amir-p).

Comment: Once check it again...Are you passing applicationContext or activity.

Answer (score 0):

Remove getApplicationContext() and pass activity context.

Answer (score 0):

Inside New Dialogue(youractivity.this, style)

Hopefully it ll solved

Comment: there is no activity that i use activity.this

Comment: Could you tell me what is the actual class type??

Comment: `RecyclerView.Adapter<ReservationTimesAdapter.ViewHolder>` btw its solved

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the dialog inside the `RecylerView.Adapter`, pass the activity object in the constructor of the Adapter and use the object itself when creating the builder -

```
    if (!activity.isFinishing()) {
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.AppTheme));
      alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.reserve_dialog);
      alertDialogBuilder.create();
      alertDialogBuilder.show();
    }
```

When you are displaying a dialog in a non activity class then you have to pass activity as a parameter.